# How to combine plugins and other in next js next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfiguration = {
  target: 'serverless', 
};

module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages], nextConfiguration);


trailingSlash: true
historyApiFallback: true
```

Comment: So whats the problem with the code? Except the trailingSlash: true
historyApiFallback: true being out in nowhere

Comment: Yes i want to put all these together as one module export.

Comment: Just put your `trailingSlash` and `historyApiFallback` into your `nextConfiguration` object.

Comment: 0


I am facing an issue in the next js production build is whenever I uploaded it on the hosting and refresh any page it gives an error 404 and whenever I go directly to specific pages its again gives error 404 but when I go from the home page its work fine.

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this:

```html
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfiguration = {
  target: 'serverless',
  trailingSlash: true
  historyApiFallback: true
};

module.exports = withPlugins([optimizedImages], nextConfiguration);
```

Comment: 0


I am facing an issue in the next js production build is whenever I uploaded it on the hosting and refresh any page it gives an error 404 and whenever I go directly to specific pages its again gives error 404 but when I go from the home page its work fine.

Please help me out